# Heisenberg's picture on complex field operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator

I've been reading David Tong's [lecture notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html) on QFT, and specifically on Lecture 2, he writes (section 2.6, eq. 2.8.3)

$$e^{i\hat{H}t}\,\hat{a}_{\vec{p}}\,e^{-i\hat{H}t}\,=\,e^{-iE_{\vec{p}}t}\,\hat{a}_{\vec{p}}$$

given the usual commutation relations considering the lowering and raising operators $\hat{a}_{\vec{p}}$, $\hat{a}^\dagger_{\vec{p}}$, which are

$$[\hat{H},\hat{a}_{\vec{p}}]\,=\,-E_{\vec{p}}\,\hat{a}_{\vec{p}}\,\,,\,\,[\hat{H},\hat{a}^\dagger_{\vec{p}}]\,=\,E_{\vec{p}}\,\hat{a}^\dagger_{\vec{p}}.$$

What I was trying to do and got stuck is

$$e^{i\hat{H}t}\,\hat{a}_{\vec{p}}\,e^{-i\hat{H}t}\,= (e^{-iE_{\vec{p}}\,t}\,\hat{a}_{\vec{p}}\,+\,\hat{a}_{\vec{p}}\,e^{i\hat{H}t})\,e^{-i\hat{H}t}\,=\,e^{-iE_{\vec{p}}\,t}\,\hat{a}_{\vec{p}}\,e^{-i\hat{H}t}\,+\,\hat{a}_{\vec{p}}.$$

How to proceed?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: Define $$a_p(t) := e^{iHt}\, a_p \,e^{-iHt}$$ and show that

$$ \frac{\mathrm d a_p (t)}{\mathrm d t} = i [H,a_p(t)] = - iE_p \, a_p(t) \quad ,$$

with $a_p(0) = a_p$. The solution of this initial value problem yields the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably expected to use use Campbell-Baker-Hausdorf:
$$
e^a be^{-a} = b+ [a,b]+\frac 12 [a,[a,b]]+\frac{1}{3!} [a[a,[a,b]]]+\ldots
$$