# Time evolution of non-interacting field operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, time-evolution, tight-binding

I learned that for a non-interacting tight-binding system $H=\sum_{n}\varepsilon_na^\dagger_n a_n$,  the time evolution of $a_n$ is simply $a_n(t)=e^{-i\varepsilon_nt}a_n$. I tried to prove this:
\begin{align}a_n(t)&=\exp({it\sum_{k}\varepsilon_ka^\dagger_k a_k})a_n\exp({-it\sum_{k}\varepsilon_ka^\dagger_k a_k})\\&=\exp({it\varepsilon_na^\dagger_n a_n})a_n\exp({-it\varepsilon_na^\dagger_n a_n})\\&=a_n\end{align}

which is apparently wrong, but I don't know where is wrong. In the above derivation I assumed $[\exp({it\varepsilon_ka^\dagger_k a_k}),a_n]=0$ for $n\ne k$ but I doubt its credibility because I didn't manage to find a general formula for $[\hat n_k^m,a_n].$

Comment: Why do you eliminate the sums over $k$ in the second line?

Comment: The last equality in your derivation is incorrect, in fact, $\exp{(it\epsilon_n a_n^\dagger a_n) } a_n \exp{(-it\epsilon_n a_n^\dagger a_n) } = e^{-i\epsilon_n t} a_n$. Try to use commutation relation between $a_n$ and $a_n^\dagger$ to prove this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heisenberg's picture on complex field operators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/701125/heisenbergs-picture-on-complex-field-operators)

Answer (score 3):

We have:
\begin{align}
e^{iHt}ae^{-iHt} = e^{\gamma aa^\dagger}a e^{-\gamma a a^\dagger}
\end{align}
Where we used the commutation relations and where we posed $\gamma = i\varepsilon t$. We will prove that $e^{\gamma aa^\dagger}a e^{-\gamma a a^\dagger}=e^{-\gamma}a$. On one side we have the derivatives which are:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d\gamma}(e^{\gamma aa^\dagger}a e^{-\gamma a a^\dagger}) =& e^{\gamma aa^\dagger}(aa^\dagger a-aaa^\dagger) e^{-\gamma a a^\dagger} = - e^{\gamma aa^\dagger}a e^{-\gamma a a^\dagger}
\\
\frac{d}{d\gamma}(e^{-\gamma}a) =& -e^{-\gamma a}
\end{align}
On the other side, we have:
\begin{align}
&\left.e^{\gamma aa^\dagger}a e^{-\gamma a a^\dagger}\right|_{\gamma=0}=a
\\
&\left.e^{-\gamma}a \right|_{\gamma=0}=a
\end{align}
Since the two expressions have the same eigenvalues of the derivative operator and the same restriction at $\gamma=0$, we conclude that the Taylor expansion of the two terms about $\gamma=0$ are identical. From the global form of these two terms, and from this previous statement, we conclude that indeed:
\begin{equation}
\boxed{e^{\gamma aa^\dagger}a e^{-\gamma a a^\dagger}=e^{-\gamma}a}
\end{equation}
This means that $e^{iHt}a e^{-iHt}=e^{-i\varepsilon t}a$. An analogous proof for $a^\dagger$ instead of $a$ sandwiched between $e^{\pm iHt}$ is possible and straightforward. This means that:
\begin{align}
a(t)=&e^{-i\varepsilon t}a
\\
a^\dagger(t)=&e^{i\varepsilon t}a^\dagger
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Another way of proving it (besides the method given by @JeanbaptisteRoux) is by using the matrix form of the operators. E.g., for a Fermion creation operator we have only two states: $|1\rangle, |0\rangle$, so that
$$
a=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix},
a^\dagger=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},
a^\dagger a = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Thus,
$$
e^{\lambda a^\dagger a}=\begin{bmatrix}e^\lambda&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
e^{\lambda^* a^\dagger a}ae^{\lambda a^\dagger a}=
\begin{bmatrix}e^{\lambda^*}&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}e^\lambda&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\e^\lambda&0\end{bmatrix}=
e^\lambda a
$$
This is easily extended to bosons.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to proove the identity you wish to prove by taking your first line as a definition:
$$a_n(t)=\exp({it\sum_{k}\varepsilon_ka^\dagger_k a_k})a_n\exp({-it\sum_{k}\varepsilon_ka^\dagger_k a_k})$$
and then use
$$[a_k,a_{k'}^{\dagger}]=i\delta_{kk'}
\Rightarrow
[\exp({it\sum_{k}\varepsilon_ka^\dagger_k a_k}),a_n]=
a_n(e^{-it\varepsilon_n}-1)\exp({it\sum_{k}\varepsilon_ka^\dagger_k a_k})$$
The identity above can be proven by Taylor expanding the exponential (fingers crossed that it is correct). Now substitute into the expression for the time-evolved annihilation operator
$$a_n(t)=[\exp({it\sum_{k}\varepsilon_ka^\dagger_k a_k}),a_n]\exp({-it\sum_{k}\varepsilon_ka^\dagger_k a_k})+
a_n\exp({it\sum_{k}\varepsilon_ka^\dagger_k a_k})
\exp({-it\sum_{k}\varepsilon_ka^\dagger_k a_k})=
a_n(e^{-i\varepsilon_nt}-1)+
a_n=a_ne^{-i\varepsilon_nt}$$
where I have also used the fact that the time-evolution operator is unitary.